# How to compute Smaller checksum for executable ranging from 4 to 6 bytes?

Tags: c++, linux, hash, checksum

I have a executable of C++ Qt project and I want to assign a checksum to it for documentation purpose so that I add can details like

**Software Version : 1.5**

**Checksum         : 0xBd3429A**

*The checksum should change whenever i update my project like add new code or remove bugs or add files or remove files.*

I know about **md5** and **sha1** and other standard hash algorithms which i can run commands and calculate the checksum but what i am looking for is smaller hashes like 4 to 6 bytes at most.
Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I believe some compilers have that capability built in - the checksum is then emitted as part of the header. If you want to roll your own, CRC32 comes to mind.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError does gcc, clang ,g++ have it?

Comment: Use the last four bytes of MD5 or SHA1.

Comment: @EricPostpischil How do you know that even a small modification to project will always change at least one byte in last four bytes, it could be possible that two different executables will have same last 4 bytes but other bytes are different or am i missing something??

Comment: @Sumeet That same kind of argument can be made of using such a small hash.  The smaller the hash the more collisions so you could do enough of an edit for it to hash back to the original value.  I'd use a full md5 or sha1.  Is there a reason you only want 4-6 bytes?

Comment: @NathanOliver reason is human should be able to manually compare equality of 2 different hashes. For hash so long as sha1 or md5 , i dont think its that easy but 4 to 6 bytes will be like 8 to 12 hexadecimal characters, far less than that.

Comment: You could use base36 or similar to present the hash to keep the number of characters down.

Comment: MD5 can be faked. SHA1 is obsolete. I'd suggest at least SHA2 and you can take as many bytes as you wish, though using the whole 64 character expression isn't going to be much worse than the "short" version unless you need to read this out over the phone or type it it in on some awkward device like a label maker. A SHA2 hash will be noticeably different in long form, as finding two hashes that are visually similar is computationally prohibitive. A single bit of difference will result in an entirely different hash.

Comment: *How do you know that even a small modification to project will always change at least one byte in last four bytes*  Both using the last 4-6 bytes of MDA5 or SHA1, and using a different CRC that produces 4-6 bytes, have the exact same problem/concern.  Sounds like you want both the fidelity of a full MDA5 or SHA1, but not the "cost" of having all the bytes.  You'll have to make a decision.

Comment: @Sumeet We have tools for that, even online ones: https://www.diffchecker.com/

Comment: Remember, the smaller your "checksum" the harder it is to trust it. At 6 hex bytes, that's not a lot of possible outputs, and I bet a sufficiently determined attacker with modest resources could spin through and find a match trivially.

Comment: Re “How do you know that even a small modification to project will always change at least one byte in last four bytes, it could be possible that two different executables will have same last 4 bytes but other bytes are different or am i missing something?”: Hash functions are designed so that small changes thoroughly change the hash. If there were patterns or limitations in how the hashes changed, they could be exploited. There may exist some cases where two strings with small differences map to the same hash, but they should exist in frequency similar to random uniform distribution.

Comment: Why not use the timestamp?

Comment: Presumably you are doing this only as a convenience for identification, not to use a hash to prevent some sort of attack on the code base. In that case, you can ignore comments about MD5 and SHA1 being obsolete—your opponent is random chance, not an analytical attacker. Random chance does not read papers showing how to spoof MD5 and has not gotten any better at it over the years.

Comment: You can have the best of both worlds and salt the crc32 sum with the timestamp: `hashit () { input_file="$1";c=$(printf "%d" "0x$(crc32 $input_file)");d=$(date '+%s');printf "%X\n" "$(($c ^ $d))"}` That would allow you to do `hash="$(hashit someprog)";printf "Hash %s was created at %s\n" "$hash" "$(date -d @$((0x$hash ^ $c)))"`

Comment: I noticed you stated *project* rather than *file*. So you want a single checksum to include all the files in your project?